# What's the equivalent of "nice" (said like the Reddit meme) in Chinese?

Tags: word-choice, word, simplified-characters, tones

How do I say "nice" as a response, in a kind of positive, "that's cool" tone, in Chinese? Like how it's said on Reddit (or elsewhere on the internet) as a response to the numbers 420 and 69.

E.g.: "I made 69 sales yesterday."

```
  "Nice."
```

I've had two suggestions so far: "好" and "很好." Is one of these correct? Neither?

It's important to get the tone across.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by 420 or 69, maybe you can provide a link, however there are a lot of phrases for you to use to praise people, esp on internet.

1. 666, THE most popular internet slang to express admiration, means smooth, cool, wonderful, well done.
2. 牛逼, pronounce **newbee**, literally means cow's p***y. means awesome. This one is also widely used in daily conversation.

Comment: Thanks! I like 牛逼. So, it's become a meme to say "nice" when someone uses the numbers 420 or 69. 

Here is an example (check out the comments): https://www.reddit.com/r/Saints/comments/vp275y/nice_69_days_until_football_season/.

Comment: I got it, so 牛逼 is definitely the way to go, esp with the presence of dirty word gives the impression of badass.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

> 爽
> shuǎng

Which roughly equates to something like:

> Awesome

Or more specifically:

> pleasurable

Sometimes even explicitly as physically pleasurable.

Somewhat apt for that usage of “nice!”

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:
*不错*

It means *Not bad* literally,but has a stronger sense of positive

You can also say *真不错* to emphasize it

Answer (score 0):

Meme expressing or internet slang is soon out of date.

What I can think of:

强, popluar 15 years ago

弓虽, it is just 强 splitted.

酷 (cool), popular 15 years ago

膜拜, I don't remember when it appears

屌, popular 10 years ago, and comparative and most form: 屌炸天, 狂霸酷炫屌炸天

666(溜溜溜)  popular 6 years ago

yyds(永远地神) popular 2 years ago and now

jjz(绝绝子) popular 2 year ago and now